# how to display only single date in kibana date histogram

Tags: kibana, date-histogram

In Kibana Date Histogram  date is displaying multiple times like below

2019-12-11 2019-12-11 2019-12-12 2019-12-12 2019-12-13 2019-12-13 -> but i need only one time to appear like this
2019-12-11 2019-12-12 2019-12-13

Comment: Please, show us the code of how you get this output?

Answer (score 0):

For your date histogram try selecting minimum interval as "Daily". It should not be Auto as that may select the interval in different way.